# Setting targetSdkVersion 31 crashes my app

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, android-12, targetsdkversion

My app was working fine till targetSdkVersion 30, as soon as I set to 31, it starts crashing in Android 12. It is working fine in Android 10 or below.

**App Build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"


   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "in.mednotes.MedNotes"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'

}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project Build gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.example.MedNotes">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" /> -->
    <queries>
        <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app makes calls -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app sends emails -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" android:label="MedNotes" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <provider android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

        <provider android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer" android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init" tools:node="remove" />

        <provider android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderInitializer" android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-downloader-init" android:exported="false">
            <!-- changes this number to configure the maximum number of concurrent tasks -->
            <meta-data android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS" android:value="5" />
        </provider>


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-3712936133525213~7043660238"/>

        <activity android:name="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:exported="false"/>
        

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am stuck, if I change the target sdk to 30, everything works on every Android. While changing to 31, the app does not work on Android 12.

**I have tried solutions provided by internet like**

1. I have added android:exported="true" in my AndroidManifest.xml to all activities, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters
2. I have added implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0' in the dependencies section of my app level build.gradle (android/app/build.gradle)

**Still the crash is happening.**

**Logcat Report show one main error even after adding 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: in.mednotes.MedNotes, PID: 31216
                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class level Javadoc for more information.
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7427)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6939)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6710)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
                 Caused by: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class level Javadoc for more information.
                    at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:162)
                    at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:198)
                    at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:42)
                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2404)
                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2374)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7422)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6939) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6710) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053) 
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class level Javadoc for more information.
                    at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.initialize(WorkManagerImpl.java:185)
                    at androidx.work.WorkManager.initialize(WorkManager.java:210)
                    at androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer.create(WorkManagerInitializer.java:39)
                    at androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer.create(WorkManagerInitializer.java:30)
                    at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:155)
                    at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:198) 
                    at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:42) 
                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2404) 
                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2374) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7422) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6939) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6710) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053) 
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

**Help Please.**

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the details of your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare Main fatal Logcat error I am getting is - `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.`    -  But I am adding implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for suggesting Logcat, i was able to find the soln. Sorry I am new that's why I didn't look up in Logcat

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by doing two things -

1. **Removing the default provider** from manifest

   ```
      <provider
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
        tools:node="remove" />
   ```

**----- replacing it with**

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

2. **Don't forget to add**

> **android:exported="true"** in my AndroidManifest.xml to all activities, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters

> implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0' in the dependencies section of my app level build.gradle (android/app/build.gradle)